# Using DataNucleus' list-ordering extension leads to empty list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

So, I have an unidirectional one-to-many relationship where I want to keep the children in an ordered list. Since they already have an "index" property, I tried to follow the advice on http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html and use the "list-ordering" extension to use that index-property to determine the order of the children instead of using an auto-generated one.

Unfortunately, as soon as I add the annotation it stops returning children and only gives me an empty list.

I recreated the problem with this simple example:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
@FetchGroup(name = "parent.children", members = {@Persistent(name = "children")})
public class Parent {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    @Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="list-ordering", value="index ASC"))
    private List<Child> children;

    // getters/setters
}

@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Child {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private Integer index;

    // getters/setters
}
```

DAO:

```
public void save(T entity) {
    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        pm.makePersistent(entity);
        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        if(tx.isActive())
            tx.rollback();
        pm.close();
    }
}

public T get(Key key, String... fetchGroups) {
     PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
     Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
     addFetchGroups(pm, fetchGroups);
     try {
         tx.begin();
         pm.setDetachAllOnCommit(true);
         T entity = (T) pm.getObjectById(entityClass, key);
         tx.commit();
         return entity;
     } finally {
         if(tx.isActive())
             tx.rollback();
         pm.close();
     }
}
```

Test code:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child(); 
child.setIndex(10);
parent.getChildren().add(child);
mParentDao.save(parent);

Parent parent2 = mParentDao.get(parent.getKey(), "parent.children");
```

Is there anything in particular that I am doing wrong?

[EDIT] Here is the related log output:

> Datastore: Putting entity of kind PARENT with key PARENT(no-id-yet)
> Datastore: Putting entity of kind CHILD with key PARENT(3)/CHILD(no-id-yet)
> Datastore:   INDEX : 10
> Datastore: Committed datastore transaction: 0
> Datastore: Started new datastore transaction: 1
> Datastore: Getting entity of kind PARENT with key PARENT(3)
> Datastore.Retrieve: Preparing to query for all children of PARENT(3) of kind CHILD
> Datastore.Retrieve:   Added sort: index ASCENDING
> Datastore.Retrieve: Query had 0 results.
> Datastore: Committed datastore transaction: 1

Comment: Works for me. I'm using v2 of the GAE plugin. Use the log to debug it, since it tells you the puts and gets to the GAE datastore

Comment: I added some of the log output. Seems fine, basically.. the entities are added correctly and do appear in the datastore, but for some reason when querying for children he receives 0 results.

Comment: I had a similar problem that puzzled me for some time. Ordered lists must be used with caution, specially if you CHANGE the ordering field before commit. Workaround: REMOVE the order tag, and implement a COMPARATOR on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Im using GAE plugin 1.7.0 with JDO and my scenario is exactly the same. I have a list of items and i need to maintain their order as well.

Now i used the app for a long period of time without doing the above changes (without implementing the feature).

Today i implemented order feature using the article and the data isn't being retrieved! the data is **present in database** but are not fetched during parent object load. Even though the list is marked with:

`@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")`

@Element(dependent = "true")

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: See my comment! There is a BUG (at least in 2.1 DN version) that prevents the ordered list to be correctly committed if you change the ORDER FIELD...